Rust workspace two crates each introduced two conflicting features of a dependency package, how to solve it
I would like to ask you a question: Two crates in the workspace each introduced two conflicting features of a dependency package. How to solve it?
# compile_error!("`vendored` and `module` features are mutually exclusive");

# crate 1
mlua = { version = "0.10.2", features = ["lua54", "module"] }

# crate 2
mlua = { version = "0.10.2", features = ["lua54", "vendored"] }

Both features are what I need. This is my normal requirement. I hope this compilation error can be solved.

You can't. Don't put them in the same workspace

It's contrary to recommendation for features not to be additive.  But given the situation, you could rename one (or both) dependencies?  It'll be a pain though, because types from the two will be distinct.
